# Whys is Celery worker using /root as home directory?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, supervisord

We are using Celery and RabbitMQ to process jobs. They are both being run by Supervisor so that they can be alive.

Some jobs expect a file in the home directory of a user A. So we run the celery worker as user A in supervisor. But when the job is being processed it is expanding the '~' as '/root'. Why is this happening? How can we ensure that it is able to find the home directory by expanding '~' as our code expects files following a '~' in a lot of places?

Comment: are you running celery workers or supervisord as root? (run `ps aux | grep celery` to see -  the first column is the user name).

Comment: By running the above command I found that Celery is run by user A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `supervisord`'s `user` configuration directive to run the celery processes as a dedicated user instead of `root`.

also you should explicity chdir to a working dir - either in your celery code or use the supervisor `directory` setting.

If you want to rely on `~` working you should probably set the invironment variable `$HOME` also. However `~` is a shell expansion which may not always work. The most portable solution is to rely on the `directory` setting.

`/etc/supervisor.d/celery.conf`

```
[program:celery]
command=/path/to/celery worker
user=celery
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/celery.log
redirect_stderr=true
directory=/path/to/celery/working/dir
environment=HOME=/path/to/celery/home
```

Comment: That is what is puzzling to me because we are already setting it to user A in the supervisord's celery config file.

Comment: ah ok. it may be that the environment variable `$HOME` is not being set - I've updated my answer to include that.